# Surjectivity and injectivity of composed function

Tags: functions

If we have f and g, two surjective functions, does $f\circ g$ be surjective ?

Same for f and g injective.

Thank you very much !

PS : I think I found something but could this be correct ?

We have the definition of injectivity :

$\forall$ $(x_0,x_1)$ $\in$ $R$, $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$ $\implies$ $x_0=x_1$

And that is the contraposed.

So : $f(g(x_0))=f(g(x_1))$

$g(x_0)=g(x_1)$

$x_0=x_1$

So $f\circ g$ is injectiv

Comment: What do *you* think? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes I tries and found out that it is surjectiv !

Comment: This is correct. Done?

Comment: First of all you should tell us which image and preimage f and g have. For two functions $f,g$ the composition $f\circ g$ does not have to exist.

Comment: Preimage ? I think we didn't see that